INSERT in for loop on a in-memory DuckDB?
Doc says:

If you must use INSERT statements to load data in a loop, avoid
executing the statements in auto-commit mode. After every commit, the
database is required to sync the changes made to disk to ensure no
data is lost. In auto-commit mode every single statement will be
wrapped in a separate transaction, meaning fsync will be called for
every statement. This is typically unnecessary when bulk loading and
will significantly slow down your program.

Is it valid for in memory DuckDB also?

what have you tried (and timed) ?

here's timing results from a trivial example
BEGIN/COMMIT for EACH BLOCK         BEGIN/COMMIT for EACH BLOCK
in MEMORY DB                        on DISK DB
500 inserts in 0.2211 sec           500 inserts in 0.7529 sec
5000 inserts in 2.2268 sec          5000 inserts in 2.2142 sec
50000 inserts in 21.4900 sec        50000 inserts in 21.2902 sec
100000 inserts in 41.9304 sec       100000 inserts in 42.6198 sec


BEGIN/COMMIT for EACH RECORD        BEGIN/COMMIT for EACH RECORD
in MEMORY DB                        on DISK DB
500 inserts in 0.4359 sec           500 inserts in 2.8458 sec
5000 inserts in 4.2788 sec          5000 inserts in 28.6838 sec
50000 inserts in 42.3491 sec        50000 inserts in 297.1263 sec
100000 inserts in 84.8005 sec       100000 inserts in 680.4954 sec


